# Call a controller method from a model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a simple question. Is it possible to call a controller method from a model? I can't seem to figure it out if it is possible. Should I just be returning something from the model to the controller rather than trying to call a method directly?
Thanks,
Pat

Comment: Being able to do this won't solve the problem of whether you should do it. Your model probably shouldn't know anything about your controller - you've probably got a flawed design rather than a problem calling a controller method.

Comment: Yea I didn't think I should be able to call a controller method in the model, but I wasn't sure. Thought i'd check with stackoverflow first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I just be returning something from the model to the controller rather than trying to call a method directly

Indeed, that's the correct approach. I'm sure there must me some ways to call some methods from the controller, but you shouldn't use them. A model must encapsulate all the logic, business and alike, of the domain problem you are working with. A controller only needs to send and receive messages between models, and back to the views.